# Not able to use webClient.DownloadStringCompleted in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient

I have a simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;

public partial class WebClient : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public WebClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
```

Now when I say `webClient.`, I expected to see DownloadStringCompleted in the IntelliSense dropdown but I dont see. And when I force use it, ofcourse it doesn't compile. What is the problem?

I am testing WebClient to see if it is of use in my project since I am fed up with the async calls and multiple threads associated with HttpWebRequest

Comment: What is the compile error you see? Is System.Net in the set of assemblies referenced by your project? Do you see any other methods in the Intellisense dropdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have for some strange reason used the name "WebClient" as the class name for your `PhoneApplicationPage`.  Hence when you use this line:-

```
 WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
```

It attempts to create another instance of your page which of course does not have a `DownloadStringCompleted` or anything else provided by the `WebClient` in the `System.Net` namespace.

I would strongly suggest you give your page a different name.  If you really did want to call your page "WebClient" then how about "WebClientPage"?

Comment: Awesome and aweful ... Awesome you could point the mistake accurately. Aweful me for doing such a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work ok here.

I opened the projected posted here.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)

Changed the WebClient usage to this

```
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

and wrote the new event handler as

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Error: " + e.Error);
    webClientTextBlock.Text = e.Result;
}
```

Worked just the same as before except I'm pulling a string down through e.Result instead of a stream.

Comment: Did you notice the class name Ravi gave the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the referrenced assemblies. Add the assemblies related to WP7 to see intellisense working properly.